# Undefined variable even if it is defined Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I get this error Undefined variable: games even if my variable is defined in controller:

My Controller:

```
 public function openingPage($id) {

      $this->getCaseData($id);

      $this->getGames();

      return view('caseopener', ['cases' => $this->data])->with('games',$games);;

    }

    private function getCaseData($id) {
        $items = DB::table('cases')->where('id', $id)->get();
        $data = @$items[0] ? $items[0] : array();
        if(isset($data->items)) {
            $data->items = json_decode($data->items, true);
        }

        $this->data = $data;
    }

   private function getGames() {
      $games = array();
      foreach ($this->data->items as $item) {
          $game = new Game($item);
          $games[] = array(
            'id' => $game->id,
            'name' => $game->name,
            'image' => $game->image,
          );
      }

      return $games;
  }
```

The problem seems to be from the getGames() function

my blade:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
                      <div class="item" style="background-image:url({{ $games->image }})">
            </div>
          @endfor
```

and if needed here is my Model 'Game' which is used in that getGames() function

```
class Game extends Model
{
  private $id;
  public $data;

  public function __construct($id) {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->id = $id;
       $this->data = $this->getData();
   }

   private function getData() {

       $game = DB::table('products')->where('id', $this->id)->first();

       if(empty($game)) return array();

       return $game;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: You `return $games` in your getGames function, but never assign it when you call `$this->getGames();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dparoli mentioned, you forgot to assign the games to the `$games` variable.

In addition there's a mistake when outputting the value: `$games->image` should be `$games[$i]['image']`. (Access a specific game and get the `image` value as an array value)

If there is any chance there might be more or less than 10 games in the future I would replace the `for` loop with `foreach`:

```
@foreach($games in $game)
    <div class="item" style="background-image:url({{ $game['image'] }})">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign `$games` in `openingPage()`, try this:

```
public function openingPage($id) {

     $this->getCaseData($id);

     $games = $this->getGames();

     return view('caseopener', ['cases' => $this->data])->with('games',$games);;
}
```

Comment: I updated it and now I get Trying to get property of non-object. This error is from the view blade now

Comment: Because `$games` is an array of arrays, not an array of objects.

Comment: I answered your original question, please accept and upvote if the original error is gone, if you have another problem open a new question.

Comment: how can I fix that? can you help me please?

Comment: Sorry I would like to be helpful but this is not the way it works here at SO, we cannot debug all your code, if you want you can edit your question and add details